# How to add print attributes to a signature widget appearance pdf in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to use Adobe Reader to print a PDF file with a seal without displaying the seal. I tried adding the "PrintState" attribute to the PDF, but it didn't work.

```
private InputStream createVisualSignatureTemplate(PDDocument srcDoc, PDRectangle rect, BufferedImage image, int pageNum, PDSignature signature) throws IOException {

    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox());
    doc.addPage(page);

    PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

    PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
    COSDictionary usage = new COSDictionary();
    COSDictionary print = new COSDictionary();
    print.setItem("PrintState", COSName.OFF);
    usage.setItem("Print",print);
    COSDictionary oc = new COSDictionary();
    oc.setItem("Usage",usage);
    oc.setItem(COSName.TYPE,COSName.OCG);
    signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.OC, oc);
    signatureField.setValue(signature);

    List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();
    acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
    acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
    acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
    acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

    widget.setRectangle(rect);
    widget.setPage(page);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

    
    PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(doc);
    PDResources res = new PDResources();
    PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    form.setResources(res);
    form.setFormType(1);
    form.setBBox(bbox);

    PDFormXObject frm = new PDFormXObject(doc);
    PDResources res1 = new PDResources();
    
    COSDictionary cosDictionary = new COSDictionary();
    cosDictionary.setItem(COSName.FRM, frm);
    res.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT, cosDictionary);
    
    frm.setResources(res1);
    frm.setFormType(1);
    frm.setBBox(bbox);

    res1.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSet);
   
    byte[] imageByte = bao.toByteArray();
    byte[] imageByte2 = bao2.toByteArray();

    PDImageXObject Sign0 = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, imageByte, null);
    PDImageXObject Sign1 = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, imageByte2, null);

    doc.save(baos);
    doc.close();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

I tried to use this code to add a print attribute to control whether the seal is printed, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, rect, signatureImage, 0, signature));
signatureOptions.setPage(visibleSignatureProperties.getPage());
doc.addSignature(signature, this, signatureOptions);

Comment: Is that Java?  C#?  You should tag the language.

Comment: You can set the hidden or the print flag.

Comment: I tried to use `widget.setPrinted(false)` to set not to print the seal, but it didn't work. Is there any specific way to use it? I didn't find it, thanks

Comment: [my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t97-_RMo34R6zYRytq0EdIWWirVL4wyV/view?usp=sharing).One of the seals does take effect, but the setting of the other seal on the first page does not take effect. The two seals are added in different ways.Thanks.

Comment: The first annotation/signature has the print flag set to true (look at it with PDFDebugger). The second signature is both a widget and has kid widgets, very weird, although that one has flags set to 0 so no printing.

Comment: This is exactly where my problem lies. I set `widget.setPrinted(false)` in the uploaded document, but it didn’t work. I don’t know if there is something wrong with the code logic.

Comment: The code in the question does not set the flag so I don't know what you tried. Maybe create a new question, as the original code used OCG concepts that went nowhere.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. You used the `CreateVisibleSignature2` example of PDFBox. However the flags of the signature are not transferred from the template, only rectangle and appearance. So it's more tricky, you need to get the signature after `doc.addSignature()` then get the widget, and then set the flag.

Comment: I managed to do it with the example with this code: `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Signature1").getWidgets().get(0).setPrinted(false);` you need to know the name of the signature field.

Comment: Woah! Seriously, thank you so much for your guidance, now I'm all set to solve this! Have an absolute blast today.

Answer (score 1):

My comment about the cause ("the flags of the signature are not transferred") was incorrect, although the solution mentioned is the same. The flags from the template ARE transferred. However PDFBox calls `setPrinted(true);` in `addSignature()` because of a requirement for PDF/A-1b files. The source code contains a long comment why this is problematic.

As mentioned in the comment, the solution is to call

```
doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Signature1").getWidgets().get(0).setPrinted(false);
```

after

```
doc.addSignature()
```

is called.